# How to properly use multiprocessing in Python by using multiple files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have 4 files -> main.py, process1.py, process2.py, process3.py. I want to run (in a loop) all processes by using multiprocessing. But when I execute my code only 1 process works.

Code main.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import process1, process2, process3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=process1)
    p2 = Process(target=process2)
    p3 = Process(target=process3)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
```

Code process1.py:

```
while True:
    print("I'm process 1")
```

The other processes are similar to process 1.

Output:

```
I'm process 1
I'm process 1
I'm process 1
I'm process 1
...
```

Comment: What is the code for each process? `process1.py`, `process2.py` and `process3.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Transform the **process1.py, process2.py and process3.py** into *functions*

main.py should be:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

from process1 import process1
from process2 import process2
from process3 import process3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=process1)
    p2 = Process(target=process2)
    p3 = Process(target=process3)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
```

and process1.py should be:

```
def process1():
    while True:
        print("I'm process 1")
```

and the others, (process2 and process3) should be turned into functions too

## Explanation

Now I have realized what is happening

when you import a .py file,
python executes it, so when you first

`import process1, process2, process3`

python starts executing the first process, so your output is **not coming** from line 7 at

```
p1.start()
```

but from line 2 at the imports
so turning them into functions makes de import just define the process1 instead of executing it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think what you want to do can be done by
*threading* module, but to do that you would need to turn the process
into functions as following (**process1.py**, for example):

```
def process1():
    while True:
        print("I'm process 1")
```

and in the main code you can use the threading module creating a thread for each process:

```
from threading import Thread

from process1 import process1
from process2 import process2
from process3 import process3

if __name__ == "main":
    p1 = Thread(target=process1)
    p2 = Thread(target=process2)
    p3 = Thread(target=process3)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
```

if you have any process that needs arguments you can send them by:

```
p1 = Thread(target=process1, args=(argument1, ))
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that the program that I'm trying to program is pretty processor focused. So I would like to use multiprocessing instead of threading.

Comment: I posted another answer that satisfies this, hope I helped you 